# What is the correct caption label for a code fragment?

Tags: documentation, report, pseudocode

I'm currently working on my Dissertation for my degree, and in writing my report, I don't know how to caption my code fragments correctly.

For example...

====================================

Diagram/Image: "Figure 1 - My Diagram"

Table: "Table 1 - Tabulated data"

Code: "????? 1 - some pseudocode"

====================================

What would you replace the question marks with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the generally accepted term is "Listing".

Answer (score 2):

I usually go for "Listing", as in:

> Listing 14: simulation harness code for a multi-threaded elevator controller.

Answer (score 2):

I would refer to your pieces of code as *Listings*.

Hence,

====================================

Diagram/Image: "Figure 1 - My Diagram"

Table: "Table 1 - Tabulated data"

Code: "Listing 1 - some pseudocode"

====================================